# Calling map with flatMap(for Option data type) but the types don't match in scala

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming

I am walking through the 'Functional Programming in Scala' exercises and in chapter 4 there is this one piece of code about the Option class that I think I am having troubles to understand.

I am asked to implement flatMap. I know that Map is meant to transform an A to a B, and then wrap it in an Option. So what even is the purpose of flatMap? If I recall correctly, flatMap implemented in lists is meant to take a function that would transform A to a List of a B. `A => List[B]`. In principle, I imagine that applies here as well. That Option is just a list with one element and I am to give it a function that is meant to take an A and wrap it inside of an Option.

I don't know how I would implement flatMap using Map. The apparent implementation is as simple as:

```
def flatMap(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = map(f) getOrElse None
```

Why does this implementation work? `f` does not have the type signature of `A=>B`, yet it calls map just fine with this signature. Obviously calling getOrElse(None) is what makes it work, because if I take that out the implementation starts to complain. But I don't understand why the scala interpreter is not complaining here. We know that `f` returns an `Option[B]`. Is That returned Option calling getOrElse, which is then unwrapping its value so it can have the right type signature? If this is the case, are there other ways to write this that would be more obvious as to why it would work?

`def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = 
    map((a)=> f(a).getOrElse(None)) // doesn't work`

Unfortunately this book does not really provide an in depth introduction to scala so I am not sure if this is syntax(pretty sure its syntactical) or logic that I am not understanding.

```
import scala.{Option => _, Some => _, Either => _, _} // hide std library `Option`, `Some` and `Either`, since we are writing our own in this chapter

sealed trait Option[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
      case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
      case None => None
  }

  def getOrElse[B>:A](default: => B): B = this match {
      case None => default
      case Some(b) => b
  }

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = 
    map(f) getOrElse(None)


  def orElse[B>:A](ob: => Option[B]): Option[B] = ???

  def filter(f: A => Boolean): Option[A] = ???
}
case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]

object Option {
  def mean(xs: Seq[Double]): Option[Double] =
    if (xs.isEmpty) None
    else Some(xs.sum / xs.length)
  def variance(xs: Seq[Double]): Option[Double] = ???

  def map2[A,B,C](a: Option[A], b: Option[B])(f: (A, B) => C): Option[C] = ???

  def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = ???

  def traverse[A, B](a: List[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = ???
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition as to the meaning of `flatMap` is perfectly correct. I believe your confusion regarding the implementation stems from the fact that `B` is a type parameter defined *per method*, and as such, it doesn't have to be have the same *value* when one method calls the other.

To show this, let's simply give the type parameters of these methods different names:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
  case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
  case None => None
}

def getOrElse[C>:A](default: => C): C = this match {
  case None => default
  case Some(b) => b
}

def flatMap[D](f: A => Option[D]): Option[D] = {
  map(f) getOrElse None
}
```

Now:

- `flatMap` has a type parameter `D`, which can be anything.
- When `flatMap` calls `map`, it assigns `Option[D]` as the value of `map`'s type parameter `B` (!). So as far as `map` is concerned, it was passed a function `f` into some type `B`, which is actually `Option[D]` for some type `D` (but `map` doesn't care!)
- When `flatMap` calls `getOrElse` - a similar thing happens, this time `getOrElse`'s type parameter `C` gets assigned the value `Option[B]` - and again, `getOrElse` just "does its thing" without caring that the output happens to be an `Option` itself

This way, the returned value is:

- `None` if the original input was `None` (because `getOrElse` would return the `default` it was passed)
- `None` if `f` returned `None` (because `getOrElse` would return the value in the `Some` that it got, which itself is a `None`)
- `Some(v)` if both the input and the result of `f` were `Some`

Which is exactly what `flatMap` should do.

Comment: Good answer. I was also confused by the syntax actually. So what's happening behind the hood is that `map(f)` returns an `Option[D]` and that is in essence calling `getOrElse` correct? So in the form of `obj function arg`. In this case, `Option[D] getOrElse None`

Comment: Correct! `map(f) getOrElse None` is equivalent to `map(f).getOrElse(None)`, see "Infix Notation" here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html